# switched out HTML for php- caused minor layout issues, unsure how to fix

Tags: php, html, css

[Live site.](http://www.frshstudio.com)

Ideally, between border-top and border-bottom, I'd like to have 3 portfolio thumbnails, a divider(.png), and 3 blog thumbnails. Below the far right of each section should be '...'(next.png).

[image: ideal]

Currently, there is a random border directly on top of "Recent Work" that shouldn't be there and the '...' button for 'Recent Blog' is below the border-bottom. What is causing this/how do I remedy?

Everything was fine before I switched out the HTML for php..

```
<?php if ($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <div id="recent">
            <div id="recent-work">
                    <p><span>Recent Work</span></p>
                    <?php while ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(130,130) ); ?></a>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <div class="next"><a href="http://www.frshstudio.com/blog/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/next.png" alt="next" id="next" /></a></div>
            </div><!-- end recent-work -->
        <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="divider">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/divider.png" alt="Section divider" id="divider" />
            </div><!-- end divider -->

        <?php if ($blog_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <div id="recent">
            <div id="recent-blog">
                    <p><span>Recent Blog</span></p>
                    <?php while ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(130,130) ); ?></a>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <div class="next"><a href="http://www.frshstudio.com/work/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/next.png" alt="next" id="next" /></a></div>
            </div><!-- end recent-blog -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

&

```
#recent {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#recent .divider {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#recent #recent-work {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}

#recent #recent-work p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#recent #recent-work p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#recent #recent-work a {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#recent #recent-blog {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
}

#recent #recent-blog p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#recent #recent-blog p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#recent #recent-blog a {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#recent .next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: _switched out the HTML for php_ .. then obviously something in your PHP output isn't exactly as it was when it was static. Can you just `diff` the output and the old static version?

Comment: what do you mean by `diff`? This is for a WP theme, so the content has to be dynamic..

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffrshstudio.com%2F

Comment: @amc: capture the original html version of the page. capture the WP version of the page, do a diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a closing `</div>` to close your first `<div id="recent">`

I think you are unintentionally nesting `<div id="recent">....<div id="recent">` without closing either of them

Comment: Thanks- got sloppy when I was up late working on this last night and needed fresh eyes to help me sort this out.

Comment: No worries - it happens.  Consider not using the same #id (`recent`) for both elements as id's are ment to be serialized (not duplicated) - oh you already changed them to classes... nice.

Answer (score 1):

You have use ids more than once and it's messing with your page. This will generate errors that search engines will use to rank you lowly. Check http://validator.w3.org/ to see for yourself.

Also you have id recent with a top border and you use the div several times. Try changing recent to a class and then change the "recent" div containing the two to a class without a border on the top.

Comment: Thank you- looks like I was too tired when I was working on this last night and got a little sloppy :/

Comment: It happens to me all the time. You solved your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Just post what the output looks like with the dynamic PHP and then the hard-coded HTML version, and compare them side by side. Whatever is different between them is the answer.

Comment: It would appear that your #recent div should contain both recent work and recent blog. Why do you have recent work outside of that container?